# Inherit look from rootsite

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I'm trying to get my subsites to inherit the look I configured (under site settings > look and feel > change the look) on the rootsite. How do I do this? Thanks in advance!

I'm using Office365 (Sharepoint online).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, according to the article below, the subsites will inherit the theme from the parent site.  Here is the article link:

[look and feel inheritance](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/choose-a-theme-for-your-publishing-site-HA102891580.aspx)

[image]

By the way, may I know whether your subsite is from another template? If so, please follow the instruction below:

1)      Since the link of Master page setting is hidden, you can change the URL to the setting page by two steps.

Copy your site URL and remove the target of URL after the default URL. See the example below:
Root URL : https://XXX.sharepoint.com/SitePages/Home.aspx
Change to : https://XXX.sharepoint.com/
Add the ‘_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx’ behind the URL from step a. See the example below:
Root URL: https://XXX.sharepoint.com/
Change to : https://XXX.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx
Note: if you get the error message, please go to check the [publishing feature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-publishing-features-479677a6-8b33-4ac7-907d-071c1c7e4518?CorrelationId=6e1896c9-bcba-49e5-b679-b7c6cf942827&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)on Team Site.

[image]

Comment: Publishing feature weren't enabled on the subsites, enable these together with the SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure, solved the problem.

Both new and existing subsites inherit from the root now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, you need to enable SharePoint Server Publishing feature if the subsite is not a publishing site.
Then when changing the look of rootsite, the look of subsite will get changed too.